# Hardware and software requirements for implementing digital signature in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography, digital-signature

I am new to digital signatures and few minutes ago I had no idea about this thing. Now I have googled it and I have got the idea how it works. But during my research I was not able to get idea that does it require any sort of hardware also. Also are there different ways to implement digital signature.

I have to submit a report to my director regarding the hardware and software requirements for implementing digital signature in my C# ASP.NET project. Any type of help will be appreciated.

Comment: It depends. If you're doing digital signatures in a regulated industry context, see what the requirements of said industry are. Otherwise, .NET has everything you might need to implement digital signatures; no additional hardware is required.

Comment: can your provide me links or article where I can get idea of what context I should use. Actually my director has no idea about this thing.

Comment: @Anton Gogolev please suggest me best possible way to do it in dotnet

Comment: For example, https://stephenhaunts.com/2014/11/23/cryptography-in-net-digital-signatures/